# Android- Help changing XML items using setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

So I have a list of cocktails and I want to click one and change three items in the XML, the Image,TextView and the link for the button. I'm having difficulty setting up and changing these items. Im currently only experimenting with two cocktails at the moment.
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/beer"
    android:id="@+id/cocktailDetail" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCocktailName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Cocktail Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCocktail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bloodymary" />

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Ingredients"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textIngredients"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Insert txt here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Preparation"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPrepration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Insert txt here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonYoutube"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="YouTube Clip"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Class

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class CocktailDetail extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cocktaildetail);
        ListView cocktail = getListView();
        cocktail.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageCocktail);
             if(position == 0){
                 imageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bloodymary));
                 Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYoutube);
                 TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCocktailName);
                 String cocktailName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Bloody_Mary");
                 t1.setText(cocktailName);
                 b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Alt-ehDc3fc")));
             }
                 });
             }else{ 
                 imageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bloodymary));
                 Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYoutube);
                 TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCocktailName);
                 String cocktailName = getIntent().getStringExtra("capirinha");
                 t1.setText(cocktailName);
                 b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Alt-ehDc3fc")));
                    }
                 });
             }
                 }
             });
           }
        }
```

list code

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    String classes[] = {"Bloody_Mary", "Capirinha", "Cosmopolitan", "Cuba_Libre", "Daiquiri", "Mai_Tai", "Manhattan", "Margarita", "Martini", "Mint_Julep", "Mojito", "Old_Fashoned", "Pina_Colada", "Screwdriver", "Singapore_Sling", "Tom_Collins", "Whiskey_Sour", "White_Russian"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);;
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, CocktailDetail.class);
            ourIntent.putExtra("Cocktails", classes);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
04-18 11:50:36.330: D/dalvikvm(32700): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 7% free 12378K/13191K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
04-18 11:50:36.335: I/dalvikvm-heap(32700): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.992MB for 358208-byte allocation
04-18 11:50:36.345: D/dalvikvm(32700): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 7% free 12727K/13575K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
04-18 11:50:36.350: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(32700): native_setup
04-18 11:50:36.350: V/MediaPlayer(32700): constructor
04-18 11:50:36.360: V/MediaPlayer(32700): setListener
04-18 11:50:36.360: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(32700): setDataSourceFD: fd 44
04-18 11:50:36.360: V/MediaPlayer(32700): setDataSource(44, 18199, 64493)
04-18 11:50:36.370: V/MediaPlayer(32700): setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-18 11:50:36.370: V/MediaPlayer(32700): prepare
04-18 11:50:36.375: V/MediaPlayer(32700): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
04-18 11:50:36.380: V/MediaPlayer(32700): New video size 0 x 0
04-18 11:50:36.380: V/MediaPlayer(32700): callback application
04-18 11:50:36.380: V/MediaPlayer(32700): back from callback
04-18 11:50:36.380: V/MediaPlayer(32700): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
04-18 11:50:36.380: V/MediaPlayer(32700): prepared
04-18 11:50:36.380: V/MediaPlayer(32700): signal application thread
04-18 11:50:36.380: V/MediaPlayer(32700): callback application
04-18 11:50:36.380: V/MediaPlayer(32700): prepare complete - status=0
04-18 11:50:36.380: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(32700): start
04-18 11:50:36.380: V/MediaPlayer(32700): start
04-18 11:50:36.385: V/MediaPlayer(32700): back from callback
04-18 11:50:36.635: I/MediaPlayer(32700): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
04-18 11:50:40.750: V/MediaPlayer(32700): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
04-18 11:50:40.750: V/MediaPlayer(32700): playback complete
04-18 11:50:40.750: V/MediaPlayer(32700): callback application
04-18 11:50:40.750: V/MediaPlayer(32700): back from callback
04-18 11:50:41.675: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(32700): release
04-18 11:50:41.675: V/MediaPlayer(32700): setListener
04-18 11:50:41.675: V/MediaPlayer(32700): disconnect
04-18 11:50:41.680: V/MediaPlayer(32700): destructor
04-18 11:50:41.680: V/MediaPlayer(32700): disconnect
04-18 11:50:42.750: D/AbsListView(32700): Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-18 11:50:43.980: D/dalvikvm(32700): GC_CONCURRENT freed 233K, 7% free 12967K/13831K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 27ms
04-18 11:50:43.980: D/dalvikvm(32700): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
04-18 11:50:43.980: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(32700): native_finalize
04-18 11:50:43.980: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(32700): release
04-18 11:50:43.985: D/AndroidRuntime(32700): Shutting down VM
04-18 11:50:43.985: W/dalvikvm(32700): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d3c2a0)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.drunktxtapp/com.drunktxtapp.CocktailDetail}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:311)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
04-18 11:50:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(32700):    at com.drunktxtapp.CocktailDetail.onCreate(CocktailDetail.java:22)
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? It would be helpful.

Comment: you cannot modify the contents of xml once set.

Comment: I just want to change the image,text and link

Comment: I'm getting bracket errors which I cant understand

Comment: also an error: The method getListView() is undefined for the type CocktailDetail CocktailDetail.java

Comment: @user2294616 we have already helped you with your last question which is related to this. Your `CocktailDetail` class is better in that. Why you are confusing yourself. I think you should read some [Android basic tutorials](https://developer.android.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `ListActivity` instead of `Activity` for `CocktailDetail` class and your XML should have a `ListView` with id `android:id="@+id/list"`

Comment: But my XML dosn't show a ListView, the ListView is shown on the menu class. Thanks for the help still getting syntax errors with brackets

Comment: @user2294616 : Post your Logcat snap.

Comment: you need to add a `ListView` in your XML if you are using `getListView `

Comment: Added LogCat and changed the CocktailDetail class so it dosn't give me any phrasing errors

Comment: android:id="@android:id/list", not android:id="@+id/list"

Comment: I don't have android:id="@android:id/list" in my XML

Comment: Oh sorry I misread..the problem is I'm not trying to put a list view in the XML I already have that implemented when I run the Menu class. Then I select an item from the list and it will change the TextView, Image and Youtube link accordingly

Comment: Do you need a `ListView` in `CocktailDetail` class?if not then you can change the TextView, Image and Youtube link by passing the corresponding values in `Intent`

Comment: yes I should remove the LIstView in CocktailDetail any suggestions on how I would change the three items when an item on the list is clicked

Comment: Look up `Intent.putExtra()`

Comment: How would I go about referencing the list from the Menu class so I could pass it into the onListItemClick

Comment: You can pass the values as `ourIntent.putExtra("Selected value", SelectedValue);`&`ourIntent.putExtra("URL link", URLLink);` and use `getIntent.getExtra("Selected value")` & `getIntent.getExtra("URL link")` in `CocktailDetail` class to get the values